# What are the arguments in getting from the theorem of Vapnik & Chervonenkis (1971) to the common form seen in Devroye, Györfi & Lugosi (1996)?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, probability-inequalities

**Context.**

The theorem below is attributed to "Vapnik, V., and Chervonenkis, A. (1971). On the uniform convergence of relative frequencies of events to their probabilities. *Theory of Probability and its Applications*, 16: 264 - 280."

> **Theorem 12.5** (Vapnik and Chervonenkis 1971). For any probability measure $\nu$ and class of sets $\mathcal{A}$, and for any $n$ and $\epsilon > 0$,
>
> $$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{A \in \mathcal{A}} \left \vert \nu_n (A) - \nu(A) \right \vert > \epsilon \right) \leq 8 s(\mathcal{A}, n)\exp \left(\frac{-n \epsilon^2}{32} \right).$$

Where $n$ is the sample size, $s(\mathcal{A}, n)$ is the $n$th shattering coefficient of $\mathcal{A}$, or growth function on a sample size of $n$.

The above statement of the theorem is extracted from section 12.4 p197 [*A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition*](https://www.szit.bme.hu/%7Egyorfi/pbook.pdf) by Devroye, Györfi and Lugosi (1996). This is the form I am most familiar with, and it also appears in section 22.8 p367 of *All of Statistics* by Wasserman (2004), section 2.2 p35 of [*Boosting: Foundations and Algorithms*](https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/2_Algorithms/Boosting_%20Foundations%20and%20Algorithms%20%5BSchapire%20%26%20Freund%202012-05-18%5D.pdf) by Freund and Schapire (2012), in this wikipedia article on [VC theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_theory#Theorem_(VC_Inequality)); as well as countless other publicly available expository notes. All sources mentioned reference the original 1971 paper, but the theorem therein differs to that of theorem 12.5.

Here is what the theorem looks like in its original guise in the [1971 paper](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece544na/fa2014/vapnik71.pdf):

> **4. Sufficient conditions for uniform convergence.**
>
> **Theorem 2.** *The probability that the relative frequency of at least one event in class $S$ differs from its probability in an experiment of size $l$ by more than $\epsilon$, for $l \geq 2 / \epsilon^2$, satisfies the probability inequality*
>
> $$\mathbb{P} \left( \pi^{(l)} > \epsilon \right) \leq 4m^S(2l) \exp \left( \frac{-\epsilon^2 l}{8} \right).$$

Where $\pi^{(l)} = \sup_{A \in S} \vert \nu_A^{(l)} - P_A \vert$ and $m^S(2l)$ is the growth function on a sample size of $2l$.

**Question.**

*What is the argument required to get from the theorem in the original 1971 paper by Vapnik and Chervonenkis to that which is stated as theorem 12.5?*

At the moment, in going from the former to the latter, I'm having trouble with the additional factor of $\exp(1 / 4)$. And also with what would relate $4m^S(2l)$, to the  $8s(\mathcal{A}, n)$.

Comment: If this is more appropriate in Mathematics.SE just say and I will delete and repost there instead.

Comment: You will need to dig into the mechanics of how the proofs of both statements operate in order to get a satisfactory answer to this question.